# Why Microsoft Help Viewer 2.0 show me source help page code

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Use - VS 2012

After restarting PC i got next - Microsoft Help Viewer 2.0 from VS 2012 show me just source code

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: That text is rendered by Internet Explorer.  Looks like you borked it.

Comment: but how? if I open anything in IE it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found reason - need to change setting in IE explorer - Enable `Open files based on content, not file extension` just reset all setting of IE

Comment: For some reason I change security level to high. After Changing it back to default (medium-high),the problem is gone.